# Вместо содержимого переменной появляется [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить проблему пожалуйста

```
function addword(){ 
  let text = document.getElementById("text").value;

  let pe = document.getElementById("divas_1");
  let p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML=text;
  pe.append(p);

  console.log(localStorage.getItem('word'));
  localStorage.setItem('word', p.toString());
}
```

Comment: Какую проблему?

Comment: Дякую за допомогу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem('word', p.outerHTML); // p.textContent?
```